# Clicking button with Selenium produces no response

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python

I am trying to automate the clicking of the "Sort by: Top picks for long stays" button at the top of the following page on [Booking.com](https://www.booking.com/searchresults.en-gb.html?ss=New%20York%2C%20New%20York%20State%2C%20United%20States&efdco=1&label=gen173nr-1FCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaMkBiAEBmAEJuAEHyAEM2AEB6AEB-AELiAIBqAIDuAK5rtuvBsACAdICJDJmYTczMTczLWE1M2QtNDRiOC04MjA5LTM0MGZhYzFhNDk2ZNgCBuACAQ&sid=3c89a9d7a0395da456dfc63c0be7a6c0&aid=304142&lang=en-gb&sb=1&src_elem=sb&src=index&dest_id=20088325&dest_type=city&ac_position=0&ac_click_type=b&ac_langcode=en&ac_suggestion_list_length=5&search_selected=true&search_pageview_id=44fb525e8ce1002a&ac_meta=GhA0NGZiNTI1ZThjZTEwMDJhIAAoATICZW46CE5ldyBZb3JrQABKAFAA&checkin=2024-03-25&checkout=2024-04-25&group_adults=10&no_rooms=1&group_children=0). My code is as follows:

```
sorting_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[data-testid="sorters-dropdown-trigger"]')))
sorting_button.click()
```

However, the code does not produce a result i.e. the dropdown list does not occur (and produces no errors).

I have tried to execute the js script (as per other posts' solutions)

```
driver.execute_script('''document.querySelector('button[data-testid="sorters-dropdown-trigger"]').click()''')
```

Would appreciate some help on this matter.

Comment: Welcome to the community! First, I'd like to ask, do you work for booking.com? Do you have permission to use test automation tools on their site? A lot of companies discourage this and even block it. It can also be seen as "unethical." Companies don't like when others use their production site even if it's for learning purposes.